# Because of Multiple collapsible divs my other elements are getting hidden while opening the collapse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problem while opening my collapses , like i have Multiple collapsible divs but when i open them , the Other divs which are not collapsible are getting hidden and some are hiding the collasible information.

What i thing the solution might be to auto adjust the distance between these divs. I did google this but didn't find anything like this. Please help

Comment: Please show the code that is not working so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

You have placed the collapsible and non collapsible divs in other positioning methods other than static (for beauty, I think). You can change those `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` styles and get automatically displacing divs.